# Why does Postgres return same ctid values for different rows across multiple tables?

Tags: database, postgresql, rdbms

My understanding of ctid was that it returns the physical location of the row on disk by giving page_id and the offset in that page where the particular row / tuple is stored. But when  try to fetch ctid for different tables, i get same ctids. So I am really confused about what exactly ctid returns? It cannot be the "actual" physical location on disk since there can only be one row at a given location on disk. Attaching a picture below of the ctid values of 5 rows in two different postgres tables:

[image]

Comment: Postgres doesn't interact directly with the disk, it loads and saves files and operates on in-memory buffers.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Debug questions require a [mre]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost correct - it's not the absolute location of the tuple, it's its location within the table. See the [doc on system columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html):

> `ctid` The physical location of the row version **within its table**. (...)

> `tableoid` The OID of the table containing this row. (...)

In a postal system analogy, `tableoid` is the building address, `ctid` is the floor and apartment number.

The `ctid`'s aren't globally unique on their own, but they are unique in combination with `tableoid`: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/krX01syi)

```sql
create table a (a int);
create table b (b int);
insert into a select generate_series(1,3) returning tableoid,ctid;
```

| tableoid | ctid |
| --- | --- |
| 16384 | (0,1) |
| 16384 | (0,2) |
| 16384 | (0,3) |

```sql
insert into b select generate_series(1,3) returning tableoid,ctid;
```

| tableoid | ctid |
| --- | --- |
| 16387 | (0,1) |
| 16387 | (0,2) |
| 16387 | (0,3) |

You might want to check out [Chapter 73. Database Physical Storage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage.html) of the official documentation.